# How do you partition results weekly in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to find the 3 highest spending customers from `Customer` (customer name, id) and `order` (order id, order amt, order date) for every week. If I run the query today, it should show the top 3 for all weeks for which order date exists.

I am thinking about doing a `Partition by` over the date (weekly), but I can't find any method to do that? Has anyone done a weekly partition of results?

I know it's not right, but this is what I have:

```
Select Top 3 customer_name, id OVER (partition by [week])
(
    Select c.customer_name, c.id, o.order_amt,
    from customer c
    Join Order o
        on c.id=o.id
    group by c.id 
)
```

Comment: Pick a database: `mysql != sql-server` and for this question an answer for one could be significantly different to an answer for the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your table structure, where `orders.order_id` is `customer.id`
use this statement

```
select
    *
from
(
    select
        details.*
        ,dense_rank() over (partition by week_num order by order_amt desc) as rank_num
    from
    (
        select
            c.id as customer_id
            ,c.name
            ,sum(o.order_amt) as order_amt
            ,datepart(WEEK,o.order_date) as week_num    
        from customer c
        join orders o on c.id=o.order_id
        group by c.id,c.name,datepart(WEEK,o.order_date)
    )details

)dets 
where dets.rank_num<=3
```

Updated : changed statement to use just 2 tables

Comment: Thanks! although there were only 2 tables and id was cust id which is there in both customer n order table. But why is the First select with dense rank outside the subquery? Can't it be 1 query?

Comment: `Dense_rank()` can be placed inside first subquery, but the statement would be less readable because of line `,dense_rank() over (partition by datepart(WEEK,o.order_date) order by sum(o.order_amt) desc) as rank_num`

Comment: Dont forget to mark it as answer. It does match your requirements from main post, including few safe features `(aggregation,dense_rank)`

Comment: why do we need outermost query select * from? Can't we use where dets.rank_num<=3 after )details ??

Comment: Window function cannot be used in `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

the query should be something like this

```
Select customer_name, id, order_amt, [week]
(
    Select c.customer_name, c.id, o.order_amt, [week],
           rn = row_number() over (partition by [week] order by o.order_amt desc)
    from customer c
    Join Order o
        on c.id=o.id
) d
where rn <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks! but will it automatically divide it into weeks with "partition by [week]"  or do I need to add some other conditions or start date/order date? Is the syntax correct?

Comment: Why are you trying to join 2 different collections by `customer id` which seems to be different id's? Does `order_id` stores `customer_id` informations?

Comment: Is this a better answer? Modified your answer to partition by datepart (week, o.order_date). 

Select customer_name, id, order_amt
(
    Select c.customer_name, c.id, o.order_amt,
       row_number() over (partition by datepart (week, o.order_date) order by o.order_amt desc) as rn
    from customer c
    Join Order o
        on c.id=o.id
    group by c.id 
) d
where rn <= 3

Comment: @Lemur yes my bad, they both store cust id.

Answer (score 0):

this is an idea,

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT c.customer_name
        ,c.id
        ,o.order_amt
        ,datepart(wk, datecol) AS Weekcol
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT c.customer_name
        ,c.id
        ,o.order_amt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Weekcol ORDER BY order_amt DESC
            ) AS rowNUm
    FROM CTE
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE1
WHERE rowNUm <= 3
```

Comment: What if 2 customers has the same number of `orders_amt`? `Dense_rank()` is better than `Row_num()`.  Second concern is the multiple operations made by customers. He can do more than 1 operation per day, so there has to be aggregation on `order_amt`.